# Copy file from a virtual server using python

Tags: python

I am trying to copy a file from a virtual machine to another remote machine using python paramiko. I am getting `Authentication failed` error message. Can you please suggest how to fix this issue.

Here is my sample code:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='MYHOST', username='username@Domain', Password='xxx', Port=22)
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp_client.get('\\xxxxxx\xxx\Copy.txt', 'C:\Knowledge\Script\PA.txt')
sftp_client.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Probably should not have the `@Domain` part in the username arg

Comment: You need to get into the habit of using "r" strings when you have embedded backslashes.  Can you `ssh` in to this host using that exact username and password?  It doesn't require a key pair?

Comment: does it work with plain ssh or putty command already ?

Comment: I tried in putty and authentication fails, the server i am trying to establish connectivity is a data VM created on Netapp. It is not a cluster, do we have to use any different syntax to download files from a VM?